# change url on successful login angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

Hi I want to change the url on successful login.
The login url is localhost/filename/login.html 
and on successful the url is localhost/filename/index.html#/birds_eye. Am using angularjs 1.3.14.
Here is the app.js code

```
var  app = angular.module('cirqSignUp', 

['cirq.controllers','cirq.services','ngRoute','ngStorage'])

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/login',{templateUrl: '/login.html',   controller: 'login'})
    .when('/birds_eye', {templateUrl: 'pages/birds_eye_view.html',   controller: 'birdsEye',reloadOnSearch: false})
    //.when('/analytics', {templateUrl: 'pages/analytics.html',   controller: 'birdsEye'})
    //.when('/items', {templateUrl: 'pages/listitems.html',   controller: 'birdsEye'})
    .when('/items/import_export', {templateUrl: 'pages/items/import_export.html',   controller: 'importExport'})
    .when('/items/categories', {templateUrl: 'pages/items/categories.html',   controller: 'forCategory'})
    //.otherwise({redirectTo: '/birds_eye'});
}])
```

and here is the controller code

```
.controller('login', ['$scope','$http','Services','$rootScope','$localStorage', '$sessionStorage','$location', function($scope,$http,Services,$rootScope,$localStorage, $sessionStorage,$location){
$('.error').hide();
$scope.loginRest = function(restLogin){
    //
    //alert(JSON.stringify(restLogin));
    var request = Services.loginDashboard(restLogin);
    request.success(function(res,status,headers,config){
        alert(status);
        //return
        $localStorage.resDataRest = res.useremailid;
        $localStorage.resTotalSales = res.dashBoard.todayssales;
        $localStorage.resTotalTransct = res.dashBoard.todaystransactions;
        console.log(JSON.stringify($rootScope.resDataRest));
        $location.path('/birds_eye');
        //afterLogin(res.useremailid);
        //console.log($rootScope.resDataRest)
    }).error(function(res,status,headers,config){
        $scope.resMsg = res.responsemessage;
            $('.error').show();
        //alert(status);
    });
};
//$rootScope.resDataRest = $scope.getVar;
/*function afterLogin(res){
    $scope.data1 = res;
    //$rootScope.afterLoginData = $scope.data1;
    alert(JSON.stringify($scope.data1));
}
```

*/}])

The problem i face using $location is the url is not getting updated and tried using windows.location but the problem with window.location is the response object which I save in a scope/rootscope variable is getting null'ed.
Please help me

Comment: `Services.loginDashboard()` is returning an `$http` promise?

Comment: Since this is a SPA using `$location.path('/birds_eye');` is all you need to go to `localhost/filename/#/birds_eye` after signing in. I am a little worried because you are saying that the url is `localhost/filename/index.html#/birds_eye`. Are you using a web server? Where are you testing this? What about your service also?

Comment: yes am using a service as well as a web server. The index.html contains the common part of the page that's why the url is like that.

Comment: @malk Yeah am getiing a response

Comment: No I mean the angular.$http service. If not, you might need to `$scope.$apply()` manually.

Comment: tired that no help :(

Comment: when using $location all the localstorage variables are becoming undefined.

Answer (score 0):

From [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) doc:

> It does not cause a full page reload when the browser URL is changed. To reload the page after changing the URL, use the lower-level API, $window.location.href.

so, try:

```
$window.location.href = '/birds_eye';
```

Comment: but will that change login.htm to index.html#/birds_eye?

Comment: when using $location all the localstorage variables are becoming undefined.